# fork() Server in C doesnt respond to client

Tags: c, linux, server, client, fork

I wrote a login server with fork in C using txt file as a database. I found a problem when im trying to use my client more than one time, that sometimes its bugs, and doesnt print anything in the console.

Here is the server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
FILE* fp;

int main() {
  int server_socket;
  socklen_t addr_size;
  struct sockaddr_in server_address;
  struct sockaddr_in client_address;
  char buffor[1024], info[21], pass[21], decision[10];
  pid_t childpid;
  fp = fopen("baza.txt", "a+");
  server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);
  if(server_socket < 0){
    printf("Błąd tworzenia socketu.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  printf("Utworzono socket\n");
  memset(&server_address,'\0',sizeof(server_socket));
  server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);
  server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  
  if ((bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*) &server_address, sizeof(server_address)))<0){
    printf("Błąd przy przybijaniu gniazda");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  listen(server_socket, 20);
  while(1){
    rewind(fp);
    int client_socket = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&client_address, &addr_size);
    printf("Połączenie od IP: %s i portu: %d\n",inet_ntoa(client_address.sin_addr),ntohs(client_address.sin_port));
    if ((childpid = fork()) == 0){
      bzero(&decision,sizeof(decision));
      bzero(&buffor,sizeof(buffor));
      bzero(&pass,sizeof(pass));
      recv(client_socket,&decision,sizeof(decision),0);
      FILE *local_fp = fdopen(fileno(fp),"a+");
      int foundlog = 0;
      int foundrej = 0;
      char line[100];
      if(strcmp(decision,"log")==0){
        rewind(local_fp);
        recv(client_socket,&buffor,sizeof(buffor),0);
        strcat(buffor,"login");
        while(fscanf(local_fp,"%100s",info)==1){
          if(strcmp(info, buffor)==0){
            send(client_socket,"Znaleziono login",strlen("znaleziono login"),0);
            foundlog = 1;
          }
        }
        
        if (foundlog==0){
          send(client_socket,"Nie ma takiego loginu", strlen("Nie ma takiego loginu"),0); 
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);     
        }
        rewind(local_fp);
        if (foundlog==1){
          recv(client_socket,&pass,sizeof(pass),0);
          strcat(buffor,"\t");
          strcat(buffor,pass);
          while(fgets(line,100,local_fp)!=NULL){
            if(strstr(line,buffor)!=NULL){
              send(client_socket,"Zalogowano",strlen("Zalogowano"),0);
              foundlog=2;
            }
          }
        }
          
        if (foundlog==1){
          send(client_socket,"Hasło nie pasuje do nazwy użytkownika",strlen("Hasło nie pasuje do nazwy użytkownika"),0);
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }  
      }
      if(strcmp(decision,"rej")==0){
        recv(client_socket,&buffor,sizeof(buffor),0);
        strcat(buffor,"login");
        while(fscanf(local_fp,"%100s",info)==1){
          if(strcmp(info, buffor)==0){
            send(client_socket,"Taki login już istnieje",strlen("Taki login już istnieje"),0);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
          }
        }
        send(client_socket,"Podany login jest wolny",strlen("Podany login jest wolny"),0);
        recv(client_socket,&pass,sizeof(pass),0);
        strcat(buffor,"\t");
        strcat(buffor,pass);
        rewind(local_fp);
        fprintf(local_fp,"%s\n",buffor);
        send(client_socket,"Zarejestrowano nowego użytkownika",strlen("Zarejestrowano nowego użytkownika"),0);
      }
      fclose(local_fp);
      close(client_socket);
      
    }
    close(client_socket);
  }
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

And client

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(){
  
  int client_socket;
  char login[20], info[20], ans[1024], pass[20]; 
  client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  
  struct sockaddr_in server_address;
  server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);
  server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  system("clear");
  
  int status = connect(client_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));
  if (status == -1){
    printf("Nie udało się połączyć do serwera\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  bzero(&login,sizeof(login));
  bzero(&ans,sizeof(ans));
  bzero(&info,sizeof(info));
  printf("--------Witaj na serwerze--------\n");
  printf("Wybierz operację\n");
  printf("1. Rejestracja\n");
  printf("2. Logowanie\n");
  scanf("%s",info);
  if((strcmp(info, "logowanie")) == 0 || (strcmp(info,"2")) == 0){
      send(client_socket,"log",strlen("log"),0);
      system("clear");
      printf("Wybrano zalogowanie\n");
      printf("Login: ");
      scanf("%s",login);
      if((send(client_socket,&login,sizeof(login),0))<0){
        printf("Błąd przy wysyłaniu\n");
      }
      if((recv(client_socket,&ans,sizeof(ans),0))<0){
        printf("Błąd przy odbieraniu\n");
      }
      printf("%s\n",ans);
      bzero(&ans,sizeof(ans));
      printf("Podaj hasło: ");
      scanf("%s",pass);
      send(client_socket,&pass,sizeof(pass),0);
      recv(client_socket,&ans,sizeof(ans),0);
      printf("Odpowiedź z serwera: %s\n",ans);
  }
  if((strcmp(info, "rejestracja")) == 0 || (strcmp(info,"1")) == 0){
      send(client_socket,"rej",strlen("rej"),0);
      system("clear");
      printf("Wybrano tworzenie nowego użytkownika\n");
      printf("Podaj swój login:");
      scanf("%s",login);
      if((send(client_socket,&login,sizeof(login),0))<0){
        printf("Błąd przy wysyłaniu\n");
      }
      if((recv(client_socket,&ans,sizeof(ans),0))<0){
        printf("Błąd przy odbieraniu\n");
      }
      printf("%s\n",ans);
      printf("Podaj swoje hasło:");
      scanf("%s",pass);
      send(client_socket,&pass,sizeof(pass),0);
      recv(client_socket,&ans,sizeof(ans),0);
      printf("Odpowiedź z serwera: %s\n",ans);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And output of the terminal

[image]

the database looks like this

```
macieklogin 123
kubalogin   123
kacperlogin 1234
```

I have tried rewriting the client and server but it didnt help at all

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It's not the problem, but you shouldn't use `&string` in the argument to `recv()`. Using an array as a function argument automatically decays to a pointer.

Comment: You should use a debugger to step through the code and see where it's hanging.

Comment: Borked for the usual trifecta:(